# Why does char occupy 7 bits when the length is 1 byte ie 8 bits?

Tags: c++, char

I've seen that the below program is taking only 7 bits of memory to store the character, but in general everywhere I've studied says that `char` occupies 1 byte of memory ie is 8 bits.

Does a single character require 8 bits or 7 bits?

If it requires 8 bits, what will be stored in the other bit?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch = 'a';
    int val = ch;
    
    while (val > 0)
    {
        (val % 2)? cout<<1<<" " : cout<<0<<" ";
        val /= 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

The below code shows the memory gap between the character, i.e. is 7 bits:

`9e9 <-> 9f0 <->......<-> a13`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char arr[] = {'k','r','i','s','h','n','a'};
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        cout<<&arr+i<<endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff999019e9
0x7fff999019f0
0x7fff999019f7
0x7fff999019fe
0x7fff99901a05
0x7fff99901a0c
0x7fff99901a13
```

Comment: Your conversion is programmed to stop when the remaining bits are zero; it'll be even fewer with the number `'0'` or various punctuation

Comment: to display the size (in bytes) of a variable or a type, use `cout << sizeof(someVariable)` of `cout << sizeof(char)`: this display the size of memory that compiler reserve for a variable of that type

Comment: @GianPaolo size getting 1 byte, but internally it is showing for the 7 bits  of gap for char to char when it stored

Comment: @ramakrishna Pointer addresses don't show bits because individual bits are not addressable. The smallest addressable unit is the byte. The reason you're seeing a difference of 7 bytes then is because your char[] array is 7 bytes.  When you write `&arr` you're getting a pointer to the whole array, not a pointer to the first element, so when you add to it you get increments of 7 bytes.

Comment: By definition, a `char` is 1 byte, this is dictated by the C++ standard. And in most implementations, 1 byte is 8 bits. Your tests are not showing this because you are simply not using any values that actually require 8bits. Also, the standard does not dictate whether `char` is signed or unsigned. If signed, the highest bit will be reserved for the sign.

Comment: "I've seen that the char data type is taking only 7 bits of memory": You've seen this where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first code sample doesn't print leading zero bits, as ASCII characters all have the upper bit set to zero you'll only get at most seven bits printed if using ASCII characters. Extended ASCII characters or utf-8 use the upper bit for characters outside the basic ASCII character set.

Your second example is actually printing that each character is seven *bytes* long which is obviously incorrect. If you change the size of the array you are using to not be seven characters long you'll see different results.

`&arr + i` is equivalent to `(&arr) + i` as `&arr` is a pointer to `char[7]` which has a size of 7, the `+i` adds `7 * i` bytes to the pointer. `(&arr) + 1` points to one byte past the end of the array, if you try printing the values these pointers point to you'll get junk or a crash: `**(&arr + i)`.

Your code should be `static_cast<void*>(&arr[i])`, you'll then see the pointer going up by one for each iteration. The cast to `void*` is necessary to stop the standard library from trying to print the pointer as a null terminated string.

Comment: `static_cast<void*>(arr[i])` -> `static_cast<void*>(&arr[i])` ? or `static_cast<void*>(arr + i)`?

Comment: @KamilCuk yep, my in head compiler failed

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with space assigned for char. You simply converting ASCII represent of char into binary.

ASCII is a 7 bit character set. In C normally represented by an 8 bit char. If highest bit in an 8 bit byte is set, it is not an ASCII character. The eighth bit was used for parity. To communicate information between computers using different encoding.

ASCII stands for American Standard Code for Information Interchange, with the emphasis on American. The character set could not represent like Arabic letters (things with umlauts for example) or latin.

To “extend” the ASCII set and use those extra 128 values that became available by using all 8 bits, which caused problems. Eventually, Unicode came along which can represent every Unicode character. But 8 bit become a standard for char.